# Gulp Removable Drive "dest" on windows error

Tags: windows, gulp, adafruit-circuitpython

The task is simple... write some CircuitPuthon code but have it under git control. The way CircuitPython works, the IoT device shows up as a drive in windows... you update the .py files, the device reboots and reloads.

However, I don't want (obviously) to have all my development happen not hat removable USB drive. So I made a folder on disk, and want to use a watch() task. Every time I change a file, it will copy the changes to the USB drive triggering a device boot. This way I can keep it all nice and newt while still having the convenience.

The problem is that when the destination is a drive root on a removable drive (like 
'e:/') the task fails...

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'e:\'
```

I would prefer to avoid elevating the command line. I just need a way to tell the dest() function to leave the folder alone if it exists. I am open to any ideas!

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var paths = {
    code: {
      src: 'source/**/*',
      dest: 'e:/'
    }
}

function code() {
    return gulp.src(paths.code.src, {since: gulp.lastRun(code)})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.code.dest));
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch(paths.code.src, code);
}

exports.watch = watch;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way? I was thinking about taking this same approach..